# Can water or liquid nitrogen mist cooling be used in part cooling?

Tags: print-quality, pla, nozzle, speed, cooling

From what I know, the speed (X, Y) of the nozzle always be slowed down to 10 mm/s-100 mm/s when printing bridge or overhang structure because of insufficient cooling. The printing speed is less than 1/10 or even only 1/100 of the maximum speed (when > 1000 mm/s). I saw someone bring up the idea of mist cooling in another question. Can we just use water mist cooling to cool the part? If not can we use liquid nitrogen mist cooling and make use of its evaporation heat absorption properly (when evaporated, it will turn into gas)

Printing material: PLA

Comment: FYI: my edits are made to be in line with the site standards as seen in the Meta post [Useful things to check for when cleaning up posts](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/500/useful-things-to-check-for-when-cleaning-up-posts).

Answer (score 1):

Liquid nitrogen cools surfaces in which contact between the liquid and the surface is achieved. Once the nitrogen becomes vapor, little to no cooling will be accomplished. One would not want to have liquid nitrogen in contact with a printing part, as the thermal shock will fracture the part as well as create thermal errors in the heater block and heated bed surface.

Water mist will deposit water on the part (if cooling is to be effected) and create similar thermal considerations, to a lesser degree compared to nitrogen.

If increased cooling is your goal, chilled dry air may be a solution with the smallest possibility of failure, although thermal errors on the heater block and heated bed should be expected.

Comment: Thanks, but the temperature difference between printed material and air will be increased slightly which will give a small contribution to cooling according to Newton's law of cooling, if we chilled the dry air. For example 125℃ PLA (weighted average) and 25℃ air has temperature difference of 100℃. 125℃ PLA (weighted average) and 0℃ has temperature difference of 125℃. The difference between them only increase 25% so the cooling rate will only increase 25%. My goal is to rapidly maximize its cooling rate so that the printer can print with no speed limit.

Comment: The status quo is the printing speed is greatly slowed down when the printed structure is overhanging or bridge.